# What is the meaning of "dazu" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Wahlkampf: Laut politscher Experten neigen Leute, die sich in einer bestimmten sozialen Schicht befinden dazu, eine spezielle Partei zu wählen."

Comment: Mh, *zu etw. neigen* is a verb-preposition junction. That's the key.

Comment: Also, there is a comma missing before *dazu* – since this might be the cause of your confusion, I am not correcting that for now.

Comment: It means nothing here... it is just a grammar vessel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase in question is

> *Leute, die ..., neigen dazu ...*.

and comes from *zu etwas neigen*, which translates directly to *to tend **to** s.th.*.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is a comma missing. The sentence should be:

“Wahlkampf: Laut politscher Experten neigen Leute, die sich in einer bestimmten sozialen Schicht befinden, dazu, eine spezielle Partei zu wählen.”

Since “die sich in einer bestimmten sozialen Schicht befinden” is a relative clause referring to “Leute” and thus should be separated from the main clause with comma.

Comment: Welcome! This is correct, but it does not answer the question. Please post only answers as answers.